# How can I change the time range of my aws cloudwatch dashboard permanently?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to set the time range of my dashboard permanently to 1 day. Unfortunately it will jump back to 3 hours when doing a browser refresh. Also each dashboard should have its own time range. So for example dashboard 1 should have 1 day time range and dashboard 2 should have 1 month time range by default. How can I achieve that?

[image: Time range selection]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the dashboard range to what you want, then click `Actions` -> `Set default time range`. In the popup, select the first option: `Always load this dashboard using the current time range setting`. Save the dashboard after that.

If you want to do it through code or CloudFormation, set the `start` parameter in the dashboard source. Like this:

```
{
  "start": "-P1D",
  "widgets": [
   ...
   ]
}
```

Comment: @tartaglia Thanks! Can you add a link to where the options and syntax rules for this are found?

Comment: Parameter is part of the dashboard body: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/CloudWatch-Dashboard-Body-Structure.html

Comment: @DejanPeretin Thanks for this, is it possible to specify the 'start' property for individual widgets in the dashboard? To prevent an extended conversation in comments, I've asked a question separately [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76165712/adding-the-start-property-for-individual-widgets-in-cloudwatch-dashboards) if that helps.

Comment: Oct 2023 update: It's now under `Actions > Settings > Set default time range`