# Adding the start property for individual widgets in Cloudwatch dashboards

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

There's a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611560/how-can-i-change-the-time-range-of-my-aws-cloudwatch-dashboard-permanently) which mentions how one could change the time range of an entire Cloudwatch dashboard, by specifying the `start` property.

My question is - Would it be possible to do the same for individual widgets?
I'd like to have a dashboard with different time ranges for different widgets in my dashboard.

What I've tried so far:

1. I've looked at the [GraphWidget class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudwatch.GraphWidget.html), and correspondingly the [Metric class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudwatch.Metric.html), and neither have the `start` property.
2. I see there're extremely similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66083174/cloudwatch-dashboard-widgets-with-independent-time-ranges) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63622111/cloudwatch-dashboards-override-time-window), which have unfortunately gone unanswered so far.

I would therefore believe this isn't supported today, but I wanted to get confirmation to ensure I'm not missing some hidden feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can have time range setting that are specific for each graph.

When you edit a graph, go to the Source tab and you can set the `start` and `end` properties.

Could be a new feature, rolled out in this batch: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/04/amazon-cloudwatch-console-capabilities-data-visualizations/

Comment: Thanks for answering Dejan. I read through your linked blog and corresponding documentation, but all of it has intructions on doing it manually through the console. What would be the right widget class to use in code in my CDK? I'm using the GraphWidget class which I've linked to in my question, and that doesn't have the start property. So which class would be the right alternative?